# How to add browser platform to MFP cordova app?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm looking for a way to add browser platform to the current mfp cordova app for testing purpose. When I tried to run `mfp cordova platform add browser`, I got the error

```
Error: Hook not implemented yet for browser
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of the commands, you're using 7.1. This release does not support the Web platform for Cordova apps.

Note that Mobile Foundation 8.0 supports standard Cordova apps, including the Web platform.

Comment: Do you have any way to exclude the unsupported plugins? In this case, it's the `cordova-plugin-mfp`

Comment: MFP Cordova 7.1 uses Cordova 3.7 which does not support the web platform. This version of built-in Cordova cannot be replaced either...

Comment: Why https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-mfp don't have browser platform? @IdanAdar

Comment: I suppose it's not yet supported.

Comment: When it was be supported? Or how can I implement an IONIC app with mfp8 for browser.? @IdanAdar

Comment: I do not have insight into the product roadmap. Contact IBM.